Терминал и cli это одно и то же?
Правильно ли говорить, что терминал - это интерфейс командной строки? Терминал и cli в операционных системах это одно и то же?

cli может выводиться не только в терминал https://hackaday.com/2020/04/15/logging-into-linux-with-a-1930s-teletype/

Вопрос терминологии. Терминалом, бывает, называют как собственно интерфейс командной строки, так и программные средства доступа к ней, а порой даже интерфейсное окно, которое формируют такие программные средства. Чаще под терминалом всё же понимают именно программное средство доступа к интерфейсу командной строки, в т.ч. удалённого.

Хорошо бы увидеть контекст. А так то да, "в быту" говорят "терминал", а в доках пишут "cli". Но понятие "терминал" шире вообще.

cli (command line interface) - это передача параметров при запуске программы. Название подразумевает именно ввод вручную из командной строки, но не всегда, могут из какого-то скрипта параметры передаваться (вообще не из терминала, и терминал может не отображаться). Терминал - это именно виртуальное устройство ввода-вывода. В нем вообще не обязана какая-то командная строка (command line) отображаться, может быть какой-то диалоговый интерфейс (какие-то текстовые меню), это уже строго говоря не command line.

Кроме cli есть понятие tui (text user interface), он отображается в терминале, может быть управление с клавиатуры или мышью, и это уже не cli. Так что равенство между терминалом и cli не нужно ставить.
